# Find out intersection of 2 pandas DataFrame according to 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intersection

I would to find out intersection of 2 pandas DataFrame according to 2 columns 'x' and 'y' and combine them into 1 DataFrame. The data are:

```
df[1]:
    x   y       id    fa
0   4   5  9283222   3.1
1   4   5  9283222   3.1
2  10  12  9224221   3.2
3   4   5  9284332   1.2
4   6   1    51249  11.2

df[2]:
    x   y        id   fa
0   4   5  19283222  1.1
1   9   3  39224221  5.2
2  10  12  29284332  6.2
3   6   1     51242  5.2
4   6   2     51241  9.2
5   1   1     51241  9.2
```

The expected output is something like (can ignore index):

```
    x   y       id    fa
0   4   5  9283222   3.1
1   4   5  9283222   3.1
2  10  12  9224221   3.2
3   4   5  9284332   1.2
4   6   1    51249  11.2
0   4   5  19283222  1.1
2  10  12  29284332  6.2
3   6   1     51242  5.2
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. Please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, a lot of us want to help you and welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thank you for reminder! I will include it next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out the intersection by joining the `x,y` columns from `df1` and `df2`, with which you can filter `df1` and `df2` by inner join, and then concatenating the two results with `pd.concat` should give what you need:

```
intersection = df1[['x', 'y']].merge(df2[['x', 'y']]).drop_duplicates()
pd.concat([df1.merge(intersection), df2.merge(intersection)])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution:

df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)

Comment: This is finding the intersection of the column names, not the intersection of the values in the dataframe.